# How can I get the product key of my PC using command prompt if my PC is corrupted?

Tags: windows-10

My PC got corrupted and is showing the message: "Diagnosing Your PC", "Preparing for Automatic Repair".

I have tried to troubleshoot it by various means but to no avail.

Now I have decided to reinstall windows 10 operating system on my PC.

However, when I am trying to search for the product key of my PC using command prompt typing the command:

```
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey
```

The command prompt displays the following message:

```
ERROR:
Description = Not found
```

How can I get the product key of my PC using command prompt if my PC is corrupted?

Is there any other way by which I can get access to my product key?

P.S: I don't have a Microsoft account.

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't use a product key, but digital entitlement. If it was already installed once, then it will be re-enabled automatically.

Comment: @harrymc Hi, can you suggest a few videos/guides which demonstrate how to install windows 10 when digital entitlement is embedded in the hardware.